How to prove $f$ is measurable in $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with following conditions?
I'm stuck in this problem:

$f$ is the extended real-valued function in $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $E$ is measurable. Prove $f$ is measurable if $\forall\varepsilon>0$ , it exists a measurable function $g$ in $E$ with $m^*(E(f\neq{g}))<\varepsilon$

where $m^*(E)$ is the exterior lebesgue measure of $E$
I try to use the property of the measurable function:

$f,h$ are the extended real-valued functions in $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. $h$ is measurable in $E$. If $m(\{x\in{E}:f\neq{h}\})=0$, $f$ is measurable in $E$.

But It's hard to construct a funtion with the property of $h$. Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{k} 
\text,k{\in}\mathbb{N}$, so I get the function series $\{g_k\}$. I considered the function $\phi=\sup\{g_k\}$ and $\psi=\inf\{g_k\}$ but It seem that they don't have the property like $h$ which I want. Maybe this idea is totally wrong at the beginning.

Hints: There exist measurable functions $g_n$ with $m^{*}(f \neq g_n) <\frac {1} {2^{n+1}}$. Note that $m^{*}(g_n \neq g_{n+1}) <\frac {3} {2^{n+2}}$ because $g_n \neq g_{n+1}$ implies $g_n \neq f$ or $g_{n+1}\neq f$. Use montonicity and sub-additivity of $m^{*}$ to show that $m^{*} (F)=0$ where $F=\lim \sup (g_n \neq g_{n+1})$. Conclude that $g =\lim g_n$ exists a.e. and is measurable. Finally show that $m^{*}(f \neq g)=0$. [$(f\neq g) \subseteq F \cup \lim \sup (f\neq g_n)$ and $m^{*}(\lim \sup (f\neq g_n))=0$ because $\sum m^{*} (f\neq g_n) <\infty$].
Notation used: $\lim \sup A_n=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m$ which is the set of points that belong to infinitely many of the sets $A_n$. I am ignoring intersection with the domain $E$. All my sets are taken to be subsets of $E$. Apologize for using $n$ as running index: the $n$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ is fixed, but my bad notation is not likely to case any confusion.

"There exist measurable functions $g_n$ with $m^{}(f \neq g_n) <\frac {1} {2^{n+1}}$. Note that $m^{}(g_n \neq g_{n+1}) <\frac {1} {2^{n+1}}$ because $g_n \neq g_{n+1}$ implies $g_n \neq f$ or $g_{n+1}\neq f$." This isn't quite correct. We only get $m^(g_n \neq g_{n+1}) \leq m^(f \neq g_n \text{ or } f \neq g_{n+1}) \leq m^(f \neq g_n) + m^(f \neq g_{n+1}) < \frac {1} {2^{n+1}} + \frac {1} {2^{n+2}} = \frac {3} {2^{n+2}}$

@Smiley1000 Thanks for the correction. But it is too minor and it doesn't affect the proof.

Thanks for your answer. Since I haven't learnt the property about the convergence of measurable function in my class, it takes me considerable time to digest what you express. Great answer! But I still have one question. To show that $(f\neq g) \subseteq F \cup \lim \sup (f\neq g_n)$, do we use the fact that$(f\neq g) \subseteq (f\neq g_n)\cup(g\neq g_n)$ and $\lim \sup A\cup{B}\subseteq\lim \sup A\cup \lim \sup B$ ?

In the complement of $\lim \sup (f \neq g_n)$ we have $f=g_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large which implies $f=\lim g_n=g$. @KrystalJustin
